# Spring security configuration not working properly

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

this is my method in my config class:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http
                .cors()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/signin", "/api/v1/auth/register")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();


        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    }
```

I have said   .anyRequest().authenticated();  at the end which should make '/api/v1/user' not return all users, but it does. why ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working correctly. I was making a mistake in the endpoints.